# How to add values in nodejs array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

I am new in nodejs. I want below result but it shows last value.

```
"child_skills" : [ 
                "Nodejs", 
                "Android", 
                "Javascript"
            ],
```

My nodejs method

```
 export function create(req, res) {
      return JobCategories.create(req.body)
        .then((JobCategoryInstance) => {      
          var childskill =  [];     
           for (var i = 0; i < JobCategoryInstance.child_categories.length; i++) {            
           childskill = JobCategoryInstance.child_categories[i].child_categoryname;
          }
           EngineerSkills.create({ skill_name: JobCategoryInstance.category_name, child_skills: childskill });
               return JobCategoryInstance;

        })
        .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
        .catch(handleError(res));
    }
```

My result is below. Why this is get only last value?

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c2d5019caa49199854872e"),
    "skill_name" : "soft",
    "date_updated" : ISODate("2017-03-10T16:32:01.437Z"),
    "child_skills" : [ 
        "Javascript"
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: What is push() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding elements to the array, you are substituting the array with one of the elements every time.

Change this:

```
childskill = JobCategoryInstance.child_categories[i].child_categoryname;
```

to this:

```
childskill.push(JobCategoryInstance.child_categories[i].child_categoryname);
```

if you want new elements to be added to the array every time.